# What is the best way to set up a PHP development environment on a Mac?

Tags: php, macos, development-environment

When I do PHP, I use **XAMPP** to set up a development environment on **Windows**, then upload to Linux servers, works very well.

I'm now passing on a PHP project to a person who has a **Mac** so he needs a local PHP dev environment. I noticed [XAMPP has a version for Mac](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) which I will recommend.

But knowing that Mac is always a bit **different**, has anyone used any other easy PHP environment setup tool for the Mac, or I could even imagine that Mac solves this issue more **elegantly** by e.g. having a web server ready to go upon first boot etc.

**What is the best way to set up a PHP development environment on a Mac?**

Comment: i think its relate to superuser , see this link :
http://superuser.com/questions/92559/set-up-apache-mysql-and-php-development-environment-on-mac-os-x-10-5

Comment: I'd like to think that a question about a solid *development* environment for running PHP on the mac is still on topic for stack overflow.  It might also fit on superuser or serverfault too...

Comment: Generally someone who can't set up their development environment won't know what to do with it either. Just saying..

Answer (score 4):

If you want a easy solution I would go with MAMP. It is a simple webserver installer so most of the time you don't really have to configure anything:
[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

If you need a userguide for installing MAMP you can find it here:
[Userguide](http://www.sawmac.com/mamp/)

Answer (score 4):

I personally use Macports to setup the PHP Development environment.
My guess is this is not the best solution right now since it requires a bit more configuration then a complete solution like Xampp but it gives you a bit more flexibility.

[Macports](http://www.macports.org/)

Once you have installed this (don't forget to install the XCode unix tools first) you can easily install packages. For instance:

```
sudo port install apache2
sudo port install php5 +apache2 
sudo port install mysql5
```

You can also easily add modules:

```
sudo port install php5-curl
```

I have setup Apache in the following way (Found this on stackoverflow) so I don't have to keep changing my apache conf file everytime I start a project.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName *.dev
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/les/Documents/workspace/%-2+/site/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

When starting a new project I add this to my /etc/hosts file and restart apache:

```
127.0.0.1       merchant.dev
```

Which will effectively run scripts in /Users/les/Documents/workspace/merchant/site/html

Lastly, I use some handy aliasses in my .bash_profile

```
alias ap='sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl'
alias apconfig='mate /opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
alias hostconfig='mate /etc/hosts'
alias dsclean='find . -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;'
```

mate is a shortcut created by textmate (really useful general purpose texteditor for mac)
dsclean is just something to keep our svn repositories clean of mac litter.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) for either windows or mac.  Its packaged nicely and runs in its own directories.

Comment: I would personally recommend this as well, and use either Eclipse PDT (community edition), NetBeans or Zend Studio as IDE (I personally use Eclipse, but will try NetBeans in the near future).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is activate the web server in System Preferences > Sharing, put your files in ~/Sites and you're good to go. Nothing "different", just easier.`</flamebait>` If you prefer a more standalone server, I'd recommend [MAMP](http://mamp.info).